# Script stops on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, hide, show

I have three radiobuttons and three dropdown menus, all three radios are always visible, and I have a script that hides the dropdown menus, if radio 1 is checked, it will show one if the dropdowns, and another if radio 2 is checked and so on.

```
$(function() {
        $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
            var state = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('radio_'  + this.id) );

            if (state) this.checked = state.checked;
        });
    });
    $(window).bind('unload', function()
    {
        $('input[type=radio]').each(function()
        {
            localStorage.setItem(
                'radio_' + this.id, JSON.stringify({checked: this.checked})
            );
        });
    });
```

this script remembers which radio was last checked, so even if I refresh the page, the same one is checked. Which also means, there is ALWAYS a radio that is checked!

I also have this following script:

```
$( function () {
        $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 1) {
                $("#exerVariNameS").show();
                $("#exerVariNameB").hide();
                $("#exerVariNameD").hide();
            } else if ($(this).val() == 2){
                $("#exerVariNameS").hide();
                $("#exerVariNameB").show();
                $("#exerVariNameD").hide();
            } else {
                $("#exerVariNameS").hide();
                $("#exerVariNameB").hide();
                $("#exerVariNameD").show();
            }
        });
    });
```

this is the one that hides the dropdowns and shows only one thats connected to whichever radio is checked, however, when the page reloads(or on form-post), all dropsdowns become visible even tho a radio is indeed still checked, and I dont know why? Isnt the script running again on page refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change event doesn't fire when a field is changed via javascript code.
As a workaround you could manually trigger it in your each function by calling

```
 $(this).trigger('change');
```

Comment: I didn't make these scripts by myself, I searched for them and copied them, so I know extremely little about scripts. So excuse me for asking this, but where exactly would I put this line? Thanks!

Comment: after this line  if (state) this.checked = state.checked;

Comment: It didn't work for me, maybe I wasn't explaining so well in my question. I believe the problem is in the second script that is hiding and showing the dropdown menus? Whenever I click a radio button the correct dropdowns hides and shows, but when I refresh the page(or post), all dropdowns become visible until i click a different radio!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1qpLwqmm/ 

I tried to create this fiddle, not exactly the same because I couldn't do the c# part but just so you can get a visual and maybe see how I mean, the 3 dropdowns are all shown, but they are only supposed to be visible with the connected radio (they have the same name so you will see) and then when I post with the button or refresh, they are all visible again!

Comment: I cleaned your code a bit, does it work, like it should? https://jsfiddle.net/h1je6fev/